# Swagger.io Slim Framework POST errors

Tags: php, apache, swagger, slim, slim-3

I used Swagger to generate a Slim framework for a server. Without editing anything, I am testing the basic functions. I have one located at `/user/login`. Here is the script I have for it:

```
$app = new Slim\App();
$app->POST('/user/login', function($request, $response, $args) {

    $queryParams = $request->getQueryParams();
    $username = $queryParams['username'];
    $password = $queryParams['password'];

    $response->write("Will not work");
    return $response;
});
$app->GET('/user/{user_id}', function($request, $response, $args) {

    $response->write('Works');
    return $response;
});
```

However, when I try to `POST` to the url using Postman (chrome app), it results in a 500 error. If I try any of the `GET` methods, it works. It only seems to be happening with the `POST` methods.

I have it running on an Ubuntu machine, with Apache2 installed with PHP. I have updated everything to the latest available versions. `ModRewrite` is enabled, and the override is set to all. Please help! I am at such as loss at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error.

Notice that I have two urls, one at `/user/login` and `/user/{user_id}`, because of the two starting `/user` urls, it confuses and doesn't know which to use, resulting in a 500 error.

Switching the `/user/login` to `/login` corrected the issue.

I feel stupid for not knowing that would happen.

Comment: That shouldn't be the problem as one is a post() and one is a get(). I tested with your code sample and it works for me. Since Slim 3.2, you should get a message in your error log showing you the actual error.